# Clicking the Button Without Refreshing the Page ASP.NET Webform

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to search for the value we wrote in the textbox without refreshing the page. But when the button is clicked, the page is refreshed. The solutions below did not work. Can you help me?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="rulosParNoTx" runat="server" CssClass="rulos-tx" placeholder="Parti no ara" type="number" ClientIDMode="Static"/> 
              <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>                               
             <asp:Button ID="rulosParNoBt" OnClick="rulosParNoBt_Click" runat="server" Text="" Style="display:none;"  ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                         </ContentTemplate>
                  <Triggers>
                      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rulosParNoBt" EventName="Click"/> 
                  </Triggers>
                   </asp:UpdatePanel>
             <script>
                 $(document).keyup(function (e) {
                     if ($('#<%=rulosParNoTx.ClientID%>').is(":focus")) {
                         $("#<%=rulosParNoBt.ClientID%>").click();                          
                     }
                     return false;
                  });
             </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQFsQ.gif)

Comment: You should create a web method for this. And you don't need the triggers markup. However, the javascript code you have needs to be ALSO placed inside of the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, you don't need (nor want) a post back trigger.

So, in theory, you need to place both the text box, and the JavaScript code inside of the update panel. However, that means a post back, and thus as you type, the text box input would mess up.

So, you can have the text box outside of the Update Panel, and it will be read-only to the code behind.

While a update panel is a REALLY cool concept, and will reduce the size of the post-back over a full page post-back?

You STILL HAVE a valid page life cycle here. Each time you type/press a key, then your going to see/have/endure a page round tip. That means on every key press, the page load event will trigger EACH time, and then the button code. While an update panel is "less" of a payload and stress on the server then a full page post-back, it still is a rather large payload to send to the server each time a key is pressed. I note this, since during testing and debugging your Web Server, your browser, and your code are all running on the SAME computer. This gives the impression of browser to server runs very fast, since no real network exists between the browser and the web server.

However, when you deploy to a real working web site, then now a MUCH slower network connection exists between the web browser and the server. This means your testing and deployment speeds will vast differ, and that key press and update panel post-back (called a partial page post back) may well look to run fast on your developer setup, but in real word use after deployment, you will find such a setup runs much slower. So, keep this in mind. In most cases, this issue is not significant but when using update panels, it is VERY signficant.

So, this code should/would work for you:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="rulosParNoTx" runat="server" CssClass="rulos-tx"
            oninput="mytest();return false;"
            placeholder="Parti no ara" type="number" ClientIDMode="Static" />

        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Button ID="rulosParNoBt" OnClick="rulosParNoBt_Click"
                    runat="server" Text="" Style="display: none;" ClientIDMode="Static" />


                <script>
                    function mytest() {
                        console.log("key");
                        $('#rulosParNoBt').click()

                    }

                </script>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And code behind could be this:

```
Protected Sub rulosParNoBt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Debug.Print($"< {rulosParNoTx.Text} >")

End Sub
```

I would consider/recommend a web method in place of your code.

## Edit: Building a search as you type

The goal here looks to be a search as you type, or so called "auto complete".

In this day and age, it makes little sense to try and build your own.

Two very popular choices are:

jQuery, and jQuery.UI has a great "auto complete" widget, and is a great choice.

However, you can also adopt the auto complete extendor from the AjaxToolkit.

Both choices are fine, and about the only advantage of the AjaxToolKit autocomplte widget is that you don't have to write (or know) any client side JavaScript.

Now, the AjaxToolkit is a RATHER large install of code for just the AutoCompate feature (you can use nuget). However, the AjaxToolkit also has popup dialogs, a fantastic up-loader control, accordiangs, and some really nice input masking for phone numbers, credit cards etc. In other words, the AjaxToolKit is well worth the efforts to install if you then use other features of the AjaxToolKit.

So, say we have this markup, and from the tool box we dropped in the AjaxToolkit "auto complete" extender. As noted, this setup is mostly drag + drop.

The resulting markup will look like this:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div style="padding:35px">
        
        <h3>Search For Hotel</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotels" runat="server" Width="360px"></asp:TextBox>

        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtHotels_Auto" runat="server" 
            BehaviorID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" 
            DelimiterCharacters="" 
            ServiceMethod="SearchHotels"
            TargetControlID="txtHotels" 
            MinimumPrefixLength="1"
            CompletionInterval="100" 
            EnableCaching="false"
            CompletionSetCount="10" >
        </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </div>
```

Note how there many options, such as how many characters you have to type before searching starts, the timing interval, and even max allowed results.

So, code behind for the web method looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub


<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function SearchHotels(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As List(Of String)

    Dim customers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)() ' Return simple list of hotels

    Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT HotelName FROM tblHotels WHERE
             HotelName Like @SearchText + '%'"

        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText)
            conn.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    customers.Add(sdr("HotelName").ToString())
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return customers

End Function
```

So, nice clean code, no need for update panel(s), and the result is thus this:

[image]

So, above demonstrates a working auto complete sample as you type, and in this day and age, it does not make sense to try and roll your own.

Comment: I applied your solution but it didn't work

Comment: Well, the posted code does work. However, see my edit for a 2nd working example of autocomplete as you type.